# A better way of handling the below program(may be with Take/Skip/TakeWhile.. or anything better)

Tags: c#-3.0

I have a data table which has only one row. But it is having 44 columns. My task is to get the columns from the 4th row till the end.

Henceforth, I have done the below program that suits my requirement.
**(kindly note that dt is the datatable)**

```
List<decimal> lstDr = new List<decimal>();           

Enumerable.Range(0, dt.Columns.Count).ToList().ForEach(i =>
{
   if (i > 3) 
    lstDr.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(dt.Rows[0][i]));
}
);
```

There is nothing harm in the program. Works fine.

But I feel that there may be a better way of handimg the program may be with Skip ot Take or TakeWhile or anyother stuff.

I am looking for a better solution that the one I implemented.

Is it possible?

I am using c#3.0

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
List<Decimal> lstDr =
  dt.Rows[0].ItemArray
  .Skip(3)
  .Select(o => Convert.ToDecimal(o))
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Skip only available from .Net 3.5

Comment: @Itay: He has to be using framework 3.5, as `Enumerable.Range` and `ToList` is not available in 3.0.

Comment: OK :)  did't thought of that :)